# Google OAuth from Windows Phone invalid signature

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, oauth

I've spent the past couple nights on this, and it's driving me mad. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

I'm trying to write a Windows Phone 7 app to connect to Google. The OAuth routine is really giving me trouble.

I've seen quite a few twitter examples, but nothing specific to Google. The code is below - every time I make the request, Google says 'invalid signature.' The base URLs match, everything seems kosher - but it refuses to take it.

```
string baseReqUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken";
string oauth_consumer_key = "CONSUMER_KEY";
string oauth_consumer_secret = "CONSUMER_SECRET";
string oauth_nonce = OAuthLibrary.OAuth.CreateNonce();
string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
long oauth_timestamp = OAuthLibrary.OAuth.CreateTimestamp();
//string scope = "https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Ffeeds%2F";
string scope = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/";
string oauth_callback = "oob";

List<string> sig = new List<string>();
sig.Add(baseReqUrl);
sig.Add("oauth_callback=" + oauth_callback);
sig.Add("oauth_conusmer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key);
sig.Add("oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce);
sig.Add("oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method);
sig.Add("oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp.ToString());
sig.Add("scope=" + scope);

string baseReq = "GET";
int i = 0;
foreach (string s in sig)
{
     if (i == 1)
     {
          baseReq = baseReq + "?" + s;
     }
     else
     {
          baseReq = baseReq + "&" + s;
     }
     i++;
}

HMACSHA1 h = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(oauth_consumer_secret));

OAuth.OAuthBase b = new OAuth.OAuthBase();
string normalizedUrl = string.Empty;
string normalizedRequestParameters = string.Empty;
string sigBase = b.GenerateSignatureBase(new Uri(baseReq.Substring(4)), oauth_consumer_key, null, null, "GET", oauth_timestamp.ToString(), oauth_nonce, "HMAC-SHA1", out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
string signature = b.GenerateSignatureUsingHash(sigBase, h);
string reqUrl = normalizedUrl + "?" + normalizedRequestParameters + "&oauth_signature=" + signature;
GetUrl(reqUrl); //this line just makes the request
```

Comment: It gave me trouble too. What OAuth library is that? You should look at https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth rather than writing your own if possible.

Comment: Having the same issue, let me know if you get anywhere and I will do the same!

Comment: Are you using OAuthBase from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs ? I spent a day trying to get that one to work with netflix and couldn't get past the "invalid signature" errors. I did find another simple example that I was able to get to work though. Check out http://www.gutgames.com/post/OAuth-Helper-in-C.aspx.